# Not able to see graphs on Controller

Tags: loadrunner

I have install LR12.60 .

When start execution with controller it runs well but not able to see any graph.
I have tried with different options on view menu under view graphs area.
Any suggestion please.

Comment: It is very hard to help you based on the information you provided. Please provide some details on the script and a screenshot of the controller while running.

Comment: Hi, Even without adding any scripts it's not showing any graphs. I have tried to add graphs in view mean options but  no luck.

Comment: I am sorry but I am unable to help you based on the information you have provided. Either add some more information to the question or contact our support team.